# Using cURL to download a zip file isn't working with follow php code

Tags: php, curl

**What I tried / am trying**

```
function download_data($target_document,$outfile_location) 
{
    log_message('info', 'Downloading every page in data set');

    do 
    {   

       $ch = curl_init ($target_document.'apiKey=' . self::$API_KEY);       
       $fp = fopen($outfile_location . "data.zip", "w");

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_exec($ch);
        $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);

        fclose($fp);

        $this->http_status = $http_status;

            if($this->http_status != 200) 
            {
                $this->data_retry_count += 1;   
            }

    } while($this->http_status != 200 && $this->data_retry_count < $this->retry_max);

        if($this->http_status == 200) 
        {

            return;

        }

}
```

Using the above code everything goes smoothly except I get a compressed (zip) with no contents. If I download the target document in the browser it works. Do I have to do something different with curl in order to get the contents of the zip file?

Disregard the `$this` variables as this function is part of a class and those variables represent the variable contained within the class.

Comment: Did you check that the output file was opened properly?

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem.

This will download ZIPs without them being empty, it was the fix for my issue not long ago.

Also You should consider `echo curl_error($ch);` for debugging.

```
<?php 
function get_file1($file, $local_path, $newfilename) { 
    $err_msg = ''; 
    echo "<br>Attempting message download for $file<br>"; 
    $out = fopen($newfilename, 'wb'); 
    if ($out == FALSE){ 
      print "File not opened<br>"; 
      exit; 
    } 

    $ch = curl_init(); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file); 

    curl_exec($ch); 
    echo "<br>Error is : ".curl_error ( $ch); 

    curl_close($ch); 
    //fclose($handle); 

}
?>
```

*Source:* http://www.weberdev.com/get_example.php3?ExampleID=4009

Answer (score -1):

sounds like you're trying to do a FTP or wget type of function with curl.  Not sure how well it works with curl.  Alternatives:

For ftp in PHP:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

for wget like functionality with PHP, you can try

file_get_contents($url)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php